# How to insert values from a masked textbox to the database?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have used this code but showing me the error

> The input string was not in correct Format

Code:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["String"].ConnectionString);

 try
 {
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("insert into TableYear where textBoxYear=" + int.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text) + ";", con);

    SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();

    int count = 0;

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        count++;
        string AY = reader.GetString(0);
        comboBoxAY.Items.Add(AY);
    }
    con.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

Comment: That's not even trying to insert data from a `MaskedTextBox` to a database.  It's simply trying to convert the contents of a `MaskedTextBox` to an `int`.  What is the value of the `Text` property when it fails and why would you be using a `MaskedTextBox` to input an `int` in the first place?

Comment: the mask property of Masked TextBox  is 0000-0000,and i want to add this in combobox. I am new to this c# so i dont know much about.

Comment: What is the value of `maskedTextBox1.Text` exactly and your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem isn't regarding insertion of `masked` textbox' content to database. The problem actually occurs while `parsing` your masked text to `int`. here:

```
int.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text)
```

you probably having a masked number in your textbox as 123-34-233 etc. in this case, you first need to clean the string. (i.e, remove spaces, dashes, and all other characters except digits (ints)). if you try to convert `235-145_234` like text to `int`, using `int.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text)`, it will obviously give an exception saying `input string was not in correct format`. because `-` cannot be parsed to integer.

Try to remove dashes from the string first, and then parse it to int. as:

```
string textBoxText = maskedTextBox1.Text;
textBoxText = textBoxText.Replace("-", "");
int number = int.parse(textBoxText);
```

and then insert it to database.

Comment: Stop concatenating together your SQL! Use **parametrized queries** instead - **ALWAYS** - please! And also: `INSERT` doesn't support a `WHERE` clause in SQL Server ..... this will **NOT** work

Comment: @user3701678 if it worked for you, please consider voting and accepting anser.

Answer (score 2):

The `INSERT` in T-SQL doesn't support a `WHERE` clause - you should use something like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableYear(Col1) VALUES(Val1)
```

In C#, you should **always** use a **parametrized query** to avoid SQL injection attacks:

```
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO dbo.TableYear(ColumnName) VALUES(@Value)");

com.Parameters.Add("@Value", SqlDbType.Int).Value = int.Parse(maskedTextBox1.Text);
```

Also you need to use `.ExecuteNonQuery()` for `INSERT`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` commands since those statements don't return a result set:

```
com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your INSERT Query is not correct, kindly remove where clause from INSERT statement